Arbitrary intersection of ideals in a Noetherian ring
If I have an intersection $\cap_{\alpha \in I} I_\alpha$ in a Noetherian ring, can I conclude that $\cap_{\alpha \in I} I_\alpha = I_{\alpha_1} \cap \dots \cap I_{\alpha_n}$ for some $\alpha_i \in I$? I think it should be possible using that the ring is noetherian but I don't know how to argue this.
And what if we know that $\cap_{\alpha \in I} I_\alpha$ is radical? I know it's easy in general to prove that any radical ideal is the intersection of the prime ideals that contain it, but from how can we conclude from this directly that because the ring is noetherian then it's the finite intersection of elements that were in the intersection from the start?

The integers are noetherian. The intersection of all prime ideals is $(0)$ (which is a radical ideal). The intersection of any finite number of ideals is not $(0)$.
